# Keep Feature Definitions in Dictionary and Rerturn the feature to the client

Tags: python, pyspark, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have below dictionary   for keeping  feature definitions as strings.

```
    features = {
  "journey_email_been_sent_flag": "F.when(F.col('email_14days') > 0,F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))",
  "journey_opened_flag": "F.when(F.col('opened_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))"
}
retrieved_features = {}
non_retrieved_features = {}
```

Or keeping it as definition itself.

```
    features = {
  "journey_email_been_sent_flag": F.when(F.col('email_14days') > 0,F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
  "journey_opened_flag": F.when(F.col('opened_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
}
```

Then below code for retrieving the feature definitions

```
 def feature_extract(*featurenames):
  for featurename in featurenames:
    if featurename in features:
      print(f"{featurename} : {features[featurename]}")
      retrieved_features[featurename] = features[featurename]
    else:
      print('failure')
      non_retrieved_features[featurename] = "Not Found in the feature defenition"
  return retrieved_features
```

And this is how I call the function for retrieving the features

```
feature_extract('journey_email_been_sent_flag','journey_opened_flag')
```

However its not working when I am trying to retrieve the future , i receive the below result when keeping the definition in dictionary

```
Out[19]: {'journey_email_been_sent_flag': Column<b'CASE WHEN (email_14days > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'>}
```

when i call the retrieval of feature as below in the dataframe.

```
.withColumn('journey_email_been_sent_flag', feature_extract('journey_email_been_sent_flag'))
```

getting below error

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and describe *exactly* what doesn't work for you.  As given, this is non-working code for which you want a code review -- not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello @Prune , did you get a chance to look at my issue.  when i use column definiton in the  features, I get the result when i retrieve it as Out[19]: {'journey_email_been_sent_flag': Column<b'CASE WHEN (email_14days > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'>}

And when I call this in the place where I want to get the feature , I get below error. Any way to fix it.
AssertionError: col should be Column


.withColumn('journey_email_been_sent_flag', feature_extract('journey_email_been_sent_flag'))

Comment: I see , the question is having a negative vote due to which , no response are getting. can you advise @prune

Comment: @UninformedUser do you have any thoughts here

Comment: @mck do you have any thoughts here

Comment: You have confused correlation and cause: the downvote and lack of response are from a common cause: you have not written a clear question to Stack Overflow guidelines.  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Also, please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  As the posting guidelines say, "Make it easy for others to help you."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by  this way

I keep the feature definition as definitions

```
    features = {
  "journey_email_been_sent_flag": F.when(F.col('email_14days') > 0,F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
  "journey_opened_flag": F.when(F.col('opened_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
}
```

And call the feature_extract function using F.lit

```
F.lit(feature_extract('journey_email_been_sent_flag').get('journey_email_been_sent_flag'))
```